# Save SealedObject Message | Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have message encrypted by RSA algorithm.

I want to save the message in this object (SealedObject) as text or byte array or anything to send it to the server.

```
        SealedObject myEncyptedMessage = new SealedObject(myMessage, cipher);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SealedObject` implements `Serializable` so you can convert it to bytes just like any other `Serializable` object. If you're not familiar with serialization, see [the tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)